# Creating a cluster using Amazon ECS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am following the ECS CLI [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_CLI_tutorial.html).

When I run the first command:
`ecs-cli up --keypair xxxxx.pem --capability-iam --size 2 --instance-type t2.medium`

I get the following error:

> ERRO[0040] Failure event                                 reason="Parameter validation failed: parameter value transin-ravi-west-1.pem for parameter name KeyName does not exist. Rollback requested by user." resourceType="AWS::CloudFormation::Stack"
>
> ERRO[0040] Error executing 'up': Cloudformation failure waiting for 'CREATE_COMPLETE'. State is 'ROLLBACK_COMPLETE'

I made sure the regions are set up properly. It still does not work. (as suggested [here](https://forums.manning.com/posts/list/37336.page))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the ecs-cli command, have you tried to pass the key name on the --keypair parameter instead of the reference for your .pem file?

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by key name. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: if you created the key via the aws cli `aws ec2 create-key-pair --key-name MyKeyPair --output text > MyKeyPair.pem` try to use the value from  --key-name parameter. If you used the aws console you named it as well, use that value.

Comment: I had that problem in the past. The cli parameter name is a bit deceiving. But the cloudformation error log you pasted points to that ("[...] for parameter name KeyName does not exist.")